# I am getting an Unexpected Indent error in a nested if block

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using a nested if block to decide the appropriate view. But I am getting an Unexpected Indent error after the if block. I am not able to find out where I am making a mistake in indentation.

```
def logged_home(request):
        names = request.user.social_auth.values_list('provider', flat=True)
        ctx = dict((name.lower().replace('-', '_'), True) for name in names)
        ctx['version'] = version
        return render_to_response('logged_home.html', ctx, RequestContext(request))


def home(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
                profile = user.get_profile()
                if profile.is_new == True:
                        return welcome(request)
                else:
                        return logged_home(request)
        else:
                return not_logged_home(request)


def signup(request):
        return render_to_response('signup.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: are you sure the indent error isn't in the **not_logged_home** or **logged_home** method/view?

Comment: Yes I am sure there is no error in **not_logged_home** or **logged_home** because they were executing without error before I edited the home view.

Comment: I suggest using `:set list` in `vim` or similar command in other text editors to show you the difference between tabs and spaces. Your IDE might be configured to always use tabs, but it's easy to get spaces / tabs misconfigured.

Comment: Why are you using mixed 4 and 8 indents?

Comment: @tmg I think I mixed up using vim and gedit which got the tabs wrong.

Comment: @sarnold I tried :set list in vim but it is only showing $ characters for end-of-line, I guess.

Comment: @tmg, probably the 8 vs 4 happened when pasting in here. Happens often. @movingahead, does `:set listchars=tab:>-` help?

Comment: Well, what I can recommend as quick solution - that's what I would do at begining - just do "dw" at begining and end of each line (using vi) and retype indents - I know it's not *desired* answer, but can be a quick workaroound :)

Comment: @sarnold The 3rd level indentation was only showing 2 tabs. I changed it but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Seriously - don't use tabs. You'll only get in trouble, like you have here. Always use spaces - in vim, for example, use `set expandtab` to get the tab key to insert spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be mixing tabs and spaces, and don't have your tab size set to 8.

Comment: I haven't mixed tabs and spaces. I only use tabs for indenting.

Comment: Use an editor that allows you to see invisible characters, that will allow you to debug it.

Comment: I used the vim command that @sarnold mentioned and modified the code to use only tabs. The modified code is at [this link](http://dpaste.com/548975/)

Comment: @moving the code you're pasting is not the code you're using, see http://dpaste.com/548980/ how on line 2 i have two tabs, and on line 3 I have 4 spaces. Now compare that to your paste.

Comment: The error was in another view file that I was importing here. That file had 4 spaces indentation which was probably causing the error.